# How should I add insulation to a metal shed?

Tags: insulation, metal, shed

I'm making a metal shed for sleeping in and working in. I think I'm going to do some slight 2x4 framing on the inside to be able to add some fiberglass insulation then drywall over that.

- Should I add some kind of vapor barrier between the metal exterior walls and the insulation?
- If I get faced insulation would that be enough?

I've never installed insulation before so I'm looking for some advice on how to go about this. I live in Wisconsin.

Comment: Since your shift key seems to be broken, I figured I'd help you out. ;) What kind of metal shed are you building and what is "slight" 2x4 framing? Please [edit] to include a drawing to indicate what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

No vapor barrier. Faced insulation alone is fine. You want the paper on the inside face of the wall cavities. This will prevent humid inside air from condensing on the metal surface during the winter.

Even if you had air conditioning inside, the air tight metal skin on the outside would prevent humid summer air from reaching the inside face of the wall cavity where it might condense and cause problems.